# NESTjs validate DTO after the request comes in

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hihi, I have a special situation where I need to validate the body of the request but instead of failing I need to wrap that error array and send it as a response afterwards.
With this I mean

```
  @Post('/archives')
  async bulkUpload(@Body() body, errors: []): Promise<ArchivesDto> {
    const archives = await this.service.save(body);
    return this.archivesMapping.getArchivesDto(archives, errors);
  }
```

```
async save(dto: ArchivesDto): Promise<any> {
   retrun ...resultof
}
```

and in the final response

```
{
archives:[] // the ones saved
errors: []// those who were bad
}
```

I mean, I can manually check each and everyone of them with joi or something like that and write a custom message, but the NestJS validation works well and I need to upgrade it a little bit

Comment: you can use an [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) to catch the error and respond with the wrapper object

Comment: I thougth that but the exception filter will not trigger the controller

Comment: you bind the filte to the controller and any errors not handled by the contoller will buble up to the exception filter. Share your attempt with us